# Return results within range and not before

Tags: ms-access

The query below returns records where DATE_SENT_TO_REGISTRATIONS falls between 2 dates :-

```
SELECT TBLBROKERAGESNEW.BROKERAGE_NAME, Count(TBLBROKERAGESNEW.BROKERAGE_NAME) AS CountOfBROKERAGE_NAME
FROM TBLQUOTESNEW LEFT JOIN TBLBROKERAGESNEW ON TBLQUOTESNEW.BROKERAGE_ID = TBLBROKERAGESNEW.ID
WHERE (((TBLQUOTESNEW.DATE_SENT_TO_REGISTRATIONS)>=#6/1/2017#) AND ((TBLQUOTESNEW.DATE_SENT_TO_REGISTRATIONS)<=#6/30/2017#))
GROUP BY TBLBROKERAGESNEW.BROKERAGE_NAME
ORDER BY Count(TBLBROKERAGESNEW.BROKERAGE_NAME) DESC;
```

Is it possible adjust this count so that it only counts Brokerages that have never had a Date Sent To Registrations before the start date (in this case June 1st) - so essentially new brokerages this month?

Comment: So the minimum `DATE_SENT_TO_REGISTRATIONS` should be >= June 1st?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HAVING` is the `WHERE` clause for grouped records.
If you try and say `WHERE Min(TBLQUOTESNEW.DATE_SENT_TO_REGISTRATIONS)>=#6/1/2017#` you'll get an error as you can't have aggregate (MIN) functions in a `WHERE` clause.

This should work:

```
SELECT      TBLBROKERAGESNEW.BROKERAGE_NAME
            , Count(TBLBROKERAGESNEW.BROKERAGE_NAME) AS CountOfBROKERAGE_NAME
FROM        TBLBROKERAGESNEW INNER JOIN TBLQUOTESNEW ON TBLBROKERAGESNEW.ID = TBLQUOTESNEW.BROKERAGE_ID
GROUP BY    TBLBROKERAGESNEW.BROKERAGE_NAME
HAVING      Min(TBLQUOTESNEW.DATE_SENT_TO_REGISTRATIONS)>=#6/1/2017#
```

To limit the upper end of dates to June add a `WHERE` clause (before the GROUP BY):
`WHERE  TBLQUOTESNEW.DATE_SENT_TO_REGISTRATIONS<#7/1/2017#`